# Angular 6: Custom group validation - set error to one field

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom validator in a reactive form which validates that field values don't overlap. 
Instead of showing every field in the whole group as erroneous, I need to set the triggering field state as invalid.

```
groupValidation(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: string} | null {

let compareToVariables = [{
      id:"t1",
      name:"Test 1",
      value: c.get('t1').value
  }, {
      id:"t2",
      name:"Test 2",
      value: c.get('t2').value
  }, {
     id:"t3",
      name:"Test 3",
      value: c.get('t3').value
  }] 

for (var x = 0; x < compareToVariables.length; x++) {      
  var compareToVariable = compareToVariables[x];

    for (var y = 0; y < compareToVariables.length; y++) {
      var valueToCompare = compareToVariables[y];

      if(valueToCompare.value === compareToVariable.value) {


        //here I want to set the status of the field that was triggered the error to 'invalid' but it doesn't work (undefined is not an object)
        this.datainputForm.setError(valueToCompare.id: 'invalid')



       let errorMessageText = 'Field' + valueToCompare.name + 'overlaps with ' +  compareToVariable.name
       return {'overlap': errorMessageText);
       }
     }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out why it can't find the form like it does in other functions that I call (such as valueChange listeners that I use to change values in other fields).

Thanks guys!

**##### EDIT ######**
Here's a stackblitz for this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012-ia5zpn

As you can see, all input fields are highlighted when just two overlap, so in the  `groupValidation()` method I want to set just the triggering (or the two fields that overlap) so I can set the html to `... || datainputForm.get('testGroup.t1').errors"` or `... || datainputForm.get('testGroup.t2').errors"` or `... || datainputForm.get('testGroup.t3').errors"`

Comment: so you want multiple error should be displayed one by one??

Comment: hi! well technically yes. I want that every error that occurs in the group only triggers its own error-class: In order for any error to show, I currently need to set `[class.invalid]="datainputForm.get('formGroup')` to every field in the group, but I need to be able to set the individual fields error class: `[class.invalid]="datainputForm.get('formGroup.t2')` to only trigger the css class for that particular field. Makes sense?